# Can't fix transform flicker in Chrome when scrolling

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transforms

I am developing a plugin for interacting with tables (dragging, resizing, etc). I'm using  CSS transforms to make the header sticky. Firefox has a totally smooth scroll but Chrome doesn't. It's odd. I have an option that allows a table to be scroll inside a container. When that is on, or if the table is inside an iframe (as the following example shows) everything's smooth. But when the container is the window, it is smooth no more.

Example with an iframe, all smooth: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gcb3fyf5/7/show/

Without the frame, without the smooth: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gcb3fyf5/7/show/light

I tried many tricks I found around here, such as:

- backface visibility hidden
- 3d transform/ translateZ(0)
- webkit-perspective = 1000

edit: I have two tables. The second one causes flicker, the first one never does.

Comment: Nice plugin.  I don't see any flicker in Chrome, so it may be specific to certain GPUs.  I'm using Intel G41 Express.

Comment: Dammit, the non-smooth link is wrong. It has a frame. Where can I upload code to test without a frame around it?
Try now, with the current links, please.

Comment: Still don't see a flicker.  (And I made sure to open the frame in a separate window.)

Comment: Are you using chrome? Also, did you activate smooth scrolling?

Comment: I am using Chrome, and Smooth Scrolling is disabled under chrome://flags.

Comment: I don't know if that's a good thing or a bad thing, but thanks for testing. I can reproduce the same behaviour in two similar PCs. Maybe it is a problem with the GPU